# doctrine unknown column

Tags: doctrine

I have a sql:

```
    Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('(t.a+t.b) as c')
        ->from('mytable t')
        ->where('t.c > 1');
```

it raise a "Unknown column c" error;

Anyone can help?

I have a try:

```
     Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('(t.a+t.b) as c')
        ->from('mytable t')
        ->orderBy('t.c');
```

It's OK;

why?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect if you are using MySQL it is because the WHERE clause does not support computed columns, you need to:

a) Repeat (t.a + t.b) > 1 in the where clause

b) use having (t.c > 1) instead of the Where clause

Comment: You need to know SQL since the DQL is converted to SQL in the background